# When will the "artfwo" PPA be updated for 12.04 Precise?

Tags: ppa

http://ppa.launchpad.net/artfwo/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/

does not exits so the packages that are supposed to be in that folder are not available.

```
.../precise/main/source/Sources
.../precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
.../precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

Will these packages be restored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this problem: `indicator-cpufreq` is now installable from the official Ubuntu repositories (universe). Hence the PPA is no longer available for Precise.